# Get cell value where to separate cells match

Tags: excel, vlookup

Ok in excel i have 2 sheets

Sheet 1 = Uptodate product datafeed
Sheet 2 = Currentlist of products on my site

Basically this is what i need done

I need to find the product id of a product that exists in both sheet 1 and sheet 2...

i have been using the following VLOOKUP to see if the product exists in both sheets.

=IF(VLOOKUP(M:M,Sheet2!S:S,1,FALSE)>0,MATCH(M:M,Sheet2!S:S,FALSE),"N")

i havent used VLOOKUP in years and im prob doing it in an outdated way any help would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I am a much bigger fan of `MATCH`  & `INDEX`.
`MATCH` Will tell you simply which row is your id found. 
So next to each id in Sheet1 I would type in following formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(M1,Sheet2!S:SJ,0),0)
```

This will comply tell you if particular id is found in the other sheet, and if it is not found formula will return `0`.

To get those id's now use (assuming that you entered my formula in row T):

```
=LARGE(T:T,1)
```

This is example to get first(Largest number) id, repeat it while changing the number to get rest of them.

Comment: '=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(M:M,Sheet2!S:S,0)),"",Sheet2!A:A)'

Works but it returns the value from Sheet2!A2 in this case when the matching row is on Sheet2!A1510

Comment: I'm sorry you've lost me, in screenshot you posted you pointed out that cell A1197 is the correct one, because Id in its is 1 or is it because the row number matches ID in first sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Without an array formula (that could be slow if you have enough products) I'd suggest two steps, first check if what is in Sheet1 is in Sheet2, say:

```
=VLOOKUP(M2,Sheet2!M:M,1,0)
```

then repeat whether what is in Sheet2 is in Sheet1.

Assumes `product id`s are listed in ColumnM on both sheets and that Row1 is for labels.

Where present in both the `product id` should be repeated and if not present in both `#N/A`.